# MVC- How can I render a page and the controller with @RenderPage (or with something else)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, controller

**My situation**: I have an `Index.cshtml`-page and a hidden `_Session.cshtml`-page. I would like render the `_Session.cshtml`-page in my `Index.cshtml`-page.

**Problem:** If I use the `@RenderPage`-statement it will render only the page and I get some Null-Exception because the application don’t fill my model (I fill the model in the controller).

Hope you can help me

Thank you

Comment: try RenderPage("_Session.cshtml", Model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 options to display a partial view:

option1:

```
@Html.Partial("_Session",model)
```

option2:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_Session",model);}
```

You need also to take care where the partial is located, if is located in the same folder with the Index, is ok, otherwise I suggest you to put the partial view in Shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use it as a layout page?

```
@{
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Session.cshtml";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

@RenderPartial() is surely what you're trying to do here?